# How to delete an object in django without rendering an html page to get the confirmation

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have created a Blog website and I want to add the functionality to delete a post object while clicking on the **Delete** button without rendering a separate HTML page rather using the confirm method in JavaScript.
And I have no idea to complete that.

Comment: You make a **POST request** to the `DeleteView`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you use a `.remove` method in model object or field
`model.field.remove(model_object)`

and use this for javascript confirm method

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">DELETE</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var r = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

use this javascript code inside template where the delete button present
[i Think this will help you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete an object without reload the webpage, you will need to use ajax.

You can define a delete url for each post same as you generate an absolute url. It is easy to do. Here is my approach using jquery ajax and function based django view.

```
#models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def delete_url(self):
        return reverse('delete-model', kwargs={'pk': self.id}

#views
def delete_model(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Model, id=pk)
    if item:
        ref = item.id
        item.delete()
        data = {'ref': ref, 'message': 'Object with id %s has been deleted' %ref}
        return JsonResponse(data)

#urls.py
path('delete/<pk>/', delete_model, name='delete-model')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".comfirm-delete").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
        var proceed = confirm('Proceed with deletion');
        if (proceed == true) {
        var endpoint = $(this).attr('data-url')
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: endpoint,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.notify({
                            // options
                            title: '<b>Message<b> ',
                            message: data.message,
                        }, {
                            // settings
                            type: 'success',
                            delay: 3000,
                            allow_dismiss: true,

                        });
                        $("#item" + data.ref).hide(1000)

                    },
                    error: function (error_data) {
                        console.log(error_data);
                        $.notify({
                title: '<b>Error</b><br>',
                message: 'Sorry, something gone wrong'
            }, {
                type: 'danger',
                delay: 3000,
            })
                    }
                })
            
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.notify({
                title: '<b>Action cancelled</b><br>',
                message: 'This one is not <span class="text-danger">Deleted</span>'
            }, {
                type: 'info',
                delay: 3000,
            })
        }
    })


})
```

```css
.comfirm-delete {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/bootstrap-notify.css" integrity="sha256-ibUTW+jDj+F8d1T1KZ4DOujRmVTFfvMKL9y14QgEaPQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
{% for obj in objects %}
 <tr id="item{{obj.id}}">
  <td>{{obj.info}}</td>
  <td data-url="{{obj.delete_url}}" class="comfirm-delete">Delete</td>
 </tr>

{% endfor %}

</tbody>

</table>
```